# Hadamard Test Circuit Missing Term

Tags: quantum-circuit, hadamard

I am trying to understand a specific Hadamard Test circuit used to calculate the direct product coefficient
$$ B_{l,m} = \langle 0|V^{\dagger} A^{\dagger}_m A_l V |0\rangle $$
where $V$ is a variational antsatz circuit and the $A$s are Pauli operators. 
The circuit with a phase gate to switch between Re[$B_{l,m}$] and Im[$B_{l,m}$] is
(note = $m = l'$ - sorry about the notation confusion)

[image]

My question is, why is there not a $V^{\dagger}$? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The circuit in your question is to perform:

[image]

Note that $|\psi \rangle = |V(\alpha)\rangle $ and
$U = A_{l^{\prime}}^\dagger A_l$

Comment: Thank you.  I misunderstand as $U = V^{\dagger} A^{\dagger}_m A_n V$.